# Multiple Imputation (mice) and "Conditional Missings" in R

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I am using `mice` in `R` to impute random missing data. I ran into a problem when attempting to account for conditional or structured `NAs` in a dataset.

A simple dataset to illustrate the problem:

```
TestData <- data.frame(Condition= c(1,1,1,1,2,NA,2,2), 
Dependent1=c(1,NA,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA),
Dependent2=c(1,12,44,1,NA,NA,NA,NA),
Dependent3=c(NA,2,3,5,NA,NA,NA,NA), 
UnaffiliatedQ=c(1,NA,3,2,27,NA,32,35))

TestData$Condition <- factor(TestData$Condition,
                         levels = c(1,2),
                         labels = c("Yes","No"))
```

In this example, the variable `Condition` is a gatekeeper question which determines whether a respondent needs to fill the next three questions, `Dependent#`. If a respondent answers with "No" and he/she does not see the next three questions, then they are marked as `NA`s - though not technically missing.

What can I do in this type of situation? If I Impute the `NA` value in the `Condition` variable, along with those in `Dependent1`, `Dependent2`, and `Dependent3`, how would I ensure that I don't end up with values in `Dependent#` that don't make sense?

I've thought of possible solutions, but none that I think would be valid or a good idea,e.g., creating a structured missing value like `-999` subsetting the dataframe based on conditional answers.

In reading through the documentation and paper of `mice`s authors  I don't see any arguments in `mice` for this type of situation. The other alternative is that I've simply been running down the rabbit hole of multiple imputation and this is not the correct use of it.

Comment: It is an interesting case. First, I think, there is a difference between "missing data" and "non-existing" data. For example, if you collected data from a sample population and one of the attributes of interest was pregnancy, obviously, male participants would skip that question - so it would not be treated as "missing data", it would rather be "non-existing data". 
In your case, I think your best bet is to partition the data based on the Condition variable and only impute the partition with "Condition=yes". In the remaining partitions, just replace the missing data with dummy encoding.

Comment: Agree with @Ahmedov above... Also, this question isn't really about programming. It should either be edited to clarify as such or migrated to CV. I am flagging for CV

Comment: @Ahmedov I appreciate the comment. I believe that is what I will end up doing. I was hoping that MICE may have an existing constraints argument for dealing with something like this, which I was glossing over. I do worry about methodology problems - thus, I'll hunt for something more statistics/methods based.

Comment: @AlexW Thanks for the input. I'm unsure of what migrating to CV is; however, if you have a way of migrating or putting it where it should be, feel free.